# Getting error while trying to start RIDE from Command Prompt using ride.py

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yPnHQ.png)I am not able to open ride from command prompt using `ride.py` and getting the following error "

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
File "C:\Users\dell i7\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\ride.py", line 21, in <module>     
from robotide import main ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'robotide'".
```

I have Python 3.7.7 installed as well WxPython and robotframework installed using Pip install command.I have Windows 10 os.
I had previously installed Python 3.6 and 3.8 as well but uninstalled them and deleted AppData as well.Still getting the same error.

Comment: You should focus on what it is saying to you: `No module named 'robotide'`

Comment: maybe is a confusion with the Python paths. Check if using the correct python with `python --version` and `python -m pip list`. You can also try to run with `python -m robotide.__init__`.

Comment: @Helio I could run Ride using "python -m robotide._init_" a couple of times.However it is not working now.I am using Python 3.7.7

Comment: I have added screenshots as image with the query.

Comment: Didn't  the Runtime Error message gave you any hint of what is wrong? It could not open settings.cfg for writting.

Also, this problem is different from your initial question.

Comment: Yes the folder got hidden as a result the file was not opening.After canging the permission settings it is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly `robotide` is not found since `RIDE library` is not available.

Check if `RIDE` is available using pip,

```
$ pip3 list
robotframework (3.2.1)
robotframework-ride (1.5.2.1)
```

or we can install RIDE library using pip,

```
pip3 install robotframework-ride
```

And check if it is installed correctly,

```
python -m robotide
```